# Bin-Ball Problem - How to find upper bound on the probability that no bin contains more than one ball.

Tags: probability

suppose we are given m balls and n bins. How to find the upper bound on the probability that no bin contains more than one ball?

Comment: Isn't $1$ an upperbound?

Comment: +1 to the above. Before attempting to find the answer to a question, it's good to first understand the question. It makes little or not sense to find "the upper bound".

Answer (score 2):

In general the probability will be

$$\prod_{i=0}^{m-1}\left( \frac{n-i}{n}\right)$$

It is easy to see that if $m\gt n$, we get this product equal to $0$.

After clarification from the OP it is now understood that we need to find a upper bound on $m$, such that the above probability doesn't exceed half.

As the OP notes, this can be achieved by solving the above for $m$, but this problem is actually very well studied, and I think it will be helpful to mention it.

This is [the birthday problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) which, in one formulation, asks that what is the number of people in a room so that probability for two sharing the same birthday is at least $1/2$. This problem is just the inverse, that the probability is at most $1/2$, and the bins can be thought of as dates, and the balls as the people.

I'll just copy the formula from the wiki page,

$$m^2-m-2n\ln(2)=0$$

$$m=\frac{1+\sqrt{1+8n\ln(n)}}{2}$$

Comment: Thanks Sabyasachi. The actual problem is to find the bound on m to ensure that probability of there being a bin containing at least 2 balls is  at least 1/2. 

I have solved the problem using the same probability you gave and got upper bound on m in terms of n.

Comment: @user141256 oh. glad I could be of help. But have you heard of the birthday problem?

Comment: Yes, I have. Started hitting the problem in different way so got stuck.